# How to get the PFN (package family names) for Microsoft Edge extensions?

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge, group-policy

I made an extension for Microsoft Edge. And I want to change a group policy in Local Group Policy Editor to prevent turning off required extensions. In the dialog indicated in the image below, I need to input the PFN (package family names) of the package. How can I get the PFN (package family names) for the extension of Edge?

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer steps below to get PFN (package family name) for the Extensions of MS Edge browser.

(1) Open Windows PowerShell window.

(2) Type below command.

```
Get-AppxPackage *Extension-Name*
```

(3) Press Enter and see the PFN (package family name).

For example, here I try to check the PFN for Tampermonkey extension and this is the result I got.

[image]

Reference:

[Find a package family name (PFN) for per-app VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/configmgr/protect/deploy-use/find-a-pfn-for-per-app-vpn)

Comment: When I run this, it doesn't list anything and when I run only 'Get-AppxPackage' it lists 114 items but, none if them is Edge extension

Comment: @vmachacek, I suggest trying to post a new thread with detailed information about your issue. Thanks for your understanding.