# How to get package family names(PFN) for Microsoft Edge extension?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I am using a registry-based approach to prevent disabling or uninstalling Microsoft Edge extensions.
However, I need a **Package Family Names** of extension to achieve this.

I tried the below command in PowerShell to get it for a particular extension but with no luck.

**> Get-AppxPackage** *ExtensionName*

source: Prevent turning off required extensions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/group-policies/extensions-management-gp

Comment: I tried the command and it can get the PFN of the extension. The result is like the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468164/how-to-get-the-pfn-package-family-names-for-microsoft-edge-extensions). Is there any error when you run the command? Have you added the `**` around the extension name? Besides, you can run PowerShell as Administrator and try again.

Comment: @YuZhou I tried for the installed extension with  PowerShell as Administrator. Also tried with ** around the extension. But nothing shows. When I try for some installed app then I get the PFN. Can you tell me the extension name for which you got the PFN?

Comment: I tried for "Grammarly for Microsoft Edge" and "Dark Mode" extensions.

Comment: I installed and tried [this extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DuvG.png) "Translator". I'll try the extensions you mentioning and let you know the result. By the way, do you install the extension in Edge Chromium or in Edge Legacy?

Comment: I Installed the extensions in Edge Chromium. However, I tried for your mentioned extension but Also did not get anything.
Tried command in PowerShell with admin right:

> Get-AppxPackage **Translator**

Is anything am I missing?

Comment: I found that if there's a space in the extension name, I can't get PFN either. But I can get PFN when there's no space in the extension name, you can check [my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elc2L.png). You can try it in other machines. I'll research further and let you know if I get any progress.

Comment: I tried for **Translator** in other machines but not getting PFN. am I missing something? I am getting PFN for installed APPs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221621/discussion-between-yu-zhou-and-jayprakash).

Answer (score 2):

After some tests and searching for the information, I found that we can only get PFN of extensions in Edge Legacy. [The doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/group-policies/extensions-management-gp) you refer to is also apply to Edge Legacy:

> You've reached the documentation for Microsoft Edge version 45 and earlier.

But now, we're using Edge Chromium and I don't find such policy which can prevent disabling or uninstalling Edge Chromium extensions. You can check [the policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#extensions-policies) which are available for Edge Chromium. So we can't use a PFN and registry-based way to achieve what you want.